# gradle zip filter: how to know the file being transformed or filtered?

Tags: gradle, filter, zip

gradle zip filter: how to know the file being transformed or filtered? e.g.,

```
task myZip(type:Zip) {

    from("/path/foo") {

        filter(MyFilter)
        filter(myTransformer)
    }
}

class MyFilter extends java.io.FilteredReader {
    public MyFilter(Reader in) {
        ...
    }
    ...
}

class MyTransformer implements Transformer<String, String> {
    ...
}
```

In both cases, is there a way to know what is the file path being processed?